# Is it possible to run some custom commands using sl4a?

Tags: android, python, sl4a

I am actually working on a demo in which i want to do some tasks when i got triggered from sl4a but according to my understanding it can only call android api's but what if i want to do some custom task or you can say that define a command that will run my custom piece of code or my API.
correct me if am wrong somewhere.

Thanx

Comment: What custom task? and what custom piece of code? You'll have to be more specific. Is your API a restful one?

Comment: like if i want to turn on the wifi and send sms in one task or you can say that if i want to run my piece of code is it possible

Comment: Sending an sms shouldn't be a problem, but unless your device is rooted, I don't think Android allows you to turn on wifi (if the user has it turned off in the preferences). Of course, I could be wrong about that. There could be some undocumented feature that I do not know about.

Comment: Are you looking to launch an SL4A script from within a different SL4A script?

Comment: @Stephan: You can control WiFi without root I think. SL4A supports it.

Comment: my purpose is to embed a custom command with in sl4a is it possible as sl4a a is open source.

Answer (score 0):

Sending an sms is very simple, using the API -

[code]

```
droid.smsSend(number, body);
```

[/code]

but turning off the wifi adapter doesn't seem to be supported in sl4a - the closest you'll come is

[code]

```
 droid.wifiDisconnect();
```

[/code]

Unless you know how to import some of the hidden java api's - which I'm still trying to figure out.

These api calls are documented in sl4a's built-in "API browser," found in the menu while editing a script, which makes it easier to determine what the native API is or isn't capable of .

I hope this helps

Comment: Any of the Java API which isn't exposed through `android.Android` is impossible to access from Python. Only the languages who's interpreter is implemented in Java can do that. Py4A uses CPython.